# Why is this not reversing the numbers in my vector when they get copied to my file?

Tags: c++

The program runs perfectly, and the numbers of my vector end up in my file, but they're not reversed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void reversevector(vector<double> &vd, int i, int j)
{
    if(i>=j) {
        double temp = vd[i];
        vd[i]=vd[j];
        vd[j]=temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
int main() {
    double n = 0;
    vector<double> vd;
    while (cin>>n) {
        vd.push_back(n);
    }

    reversevector(vd,0,vd.size()-1);

    ofstream ofs("reversedlist.txt");

    if(!ofs) {
        cout<<"error";
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<vd.size(); i++){
        ofs<<vd[i];
    }

    ofs.close();
}
```

For example: If I put 12345 into my vector, it should print out 54321 into my file. When I open my file, it still contains 12345.

Comment: Consider just `std::reverse_copy(std::begin(vd), std::end(vd), std::ostream_iterator<double>(ofs));`. That aside, there's `std::reverse`, so no need to make your own.

Comment: Interesting choice of words. If your program doesn't do what you want it to, I'd hardly consider that "running perfectly". :)

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
if (i >= j)
```

in the `reversevector` function should be

```
while (i < j)
```

Otherwise, you conditionally swap the first and the last number, and then quit right away.

Comment: You mean `while (j < i)` probably.

Answer (score 3):

You call your method with, say:

```
reversevector( {1,2,3,4,5} , 0, 4 )
```

which then goes into

```
if (0>=4) {
  ...
 }
```

and then exits the method - nothing happens.

Of course, you could have spotted this yourself **if you had debugged**.

Answer (score 2):

There is no loop in reverse vector. It will run once and then exit. You need to loop over the array and replace for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `reversevector` function swaps at most two elements. You have to swap more than two elements to reverse a vector. Since the test condition in the `if` will be false anyway, it actually won't do anything at all.